# Meu layout não renderiza

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Eu estava assistindo e copiando um código da primeira aula de *Material Design* do Thiengo Calopsita do *youtube*, Acontece que o arquivo *xml* da `activity_main` e da `toolbar_bottom` não está renderizando no *Android Studio*, de acordo com o erro, tem algum problema na classe `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`!

Como fazer o layout renderizar?

segue o código *activity_main.xml*

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tb_main"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/tb_main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/inc_tb_bottom"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_Bottom"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Segue o código da *toolbar_bottom.xml*

```xml
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/tb_bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/Theme.MyThemeBottom">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_settings"
        android:src="@drawable/settings"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Segue o erro gerado:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: View_theme
    at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ViewUtils.themifyContext(ViewUtils.java:124)
    at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:198)
    at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:379)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:99)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallback.loadView(LayoutlibCallback.java:172)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:132)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:400)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:332)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:688)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:677)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:677)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:815)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:646)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:82)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:589)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:584)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: Vá em `Build > Clean Project` em seu Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

1. Experimenta trocar `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` por `< Toolbar`
2. E trocar `app:theme="@style/Theme.MyThemeBottom">` por `android:theme="@style/Theme.MyThemeBottom">`

Feito isso da um *Clean Build*.

Answer (score 0):

Seguinte: Na Janela Preview logo no topo tem uma linha com vários ícones, o útimo ícone é o bonequinho android com o titulo : "Android Version to use when rendering layouts..." troca de 22 para 21 que resolve